# How do I get the performed operation and affected table from a database trigger in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I get the performed operation and affected table from a database trigger in oracle?

I want to create a trigger for a schema in Oracle which gets executed `on drop or alter or create on database` So I need something similar like inserting, updating, deleting but for DDL statements, and somehow I need to know the affected table and schema.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation has a list of the [event attribute functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg14evt.htm#1000872) that you can access.  It looks like you'd want `ora_sysevent` for the event along with `ora_dict_obj_name` and `ora_dict_obj_owner` to identify the object in question.

Comment: thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for :)